# TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" error in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

How to setup my nodejs,express project with typescript properly getting this error TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts". how to configure things properly?

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext", 
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true 
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

package.json

```
{
"name": "backend",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"type":"module",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon --exec ts-node index.ts",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/node": "^20.5.7",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

index.ts

```
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send('Hello, TypeScript with Express!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is probably due to the conflict between TypeScript and ECMAScript modules (ESM) in your setup.

1. You've specified `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`, which sets the package to use ECMAScript modules. This conflicts with TypeScript's CommonJS or ESNext module system.
2. Your `start` script uses `ts-node` to run TypeScript files directly, but your `package.json` is indicating that your Node.js application should treat files as ESM, which is likely causing the unknown file extension issue for `.ts`.

Here are a couple of ways to resolve this:

#### Option 1: Use CommonJS

Remove `"type": "module"` from `package.json` and modify `tsconfig.json`.

#### Option 2: Use ES Modules with TypeScript

Keep `"type": "module"` in your `package.json` but change the start script to compile TypeScript first.

Note: If you use this approach, remember that you'll have to rename your `index.ts` imports to include file extensions, as per ES Modules specifications.

#### General Tips

- Install the required types and packages:

```bash
npm install --save-dev @types/node @types/express ts-node typescript
```

- If you decide to remove `"type": "module"`, your `start` script using `ts-node` should work without issue.
- If you still encounter issues with Nodemon, try installing it globally (`npm install -g nodemon`) or as a dev dependency (`npm install --save-dev nodemon`) and ensure it's the latest version.

Comment: Can you help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77207692/error-error-cannot-find-module-ffmpeg-wasm-core-mt-require-stack?